# Calculating time between two dates excluding weekends when an input is during the weekend?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to calculate the time difference between two dates to exclude weekends and holidays in Excel. The issue I am running into is that sometimes an event happens during a weekend.

For example I am dealing with system inputs to calculate the time between when something was added to the system and when someone worked the issue.

I have the input time in Cell A1 and the completed time in Cell B1. I currently use the following formula NETWORKDAYS but I don't like how that returns full days instead I would like to know the hours. When using the NETWORKDAYS formula along with MOD I get an error for anytime something happened during the weekend.

I am dealing with a system where anyone can input something at any time but we do not respond during non business hours unless the system automtically responds for us.

Comment: Have you looked at the WORKDAY function?  That deals with whole day counts.  If you are talking about hours, do you just want to convert a date/time difference minus excluded days to hours or are you talking about "business hours", where only hours during the workday count?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in NETWORKHOURS function.  You will have to implement it yourself or find examples online.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

> 1) Enter Start Day/Time in cell **A1** and End Day/Time in cell **B1**
>
> [image: Start/End Date/Time]
>
> 2) Create a named range called **Holidays**, which contains any holidays.  [Example of creating a named range.](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html)
>
> 3) Copy the below formula, paste into the **Formula Bar** for cell **D1**, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=IFERROR(MROUND(NETWORKDAYS(
IF(OR(
          WEEKDAY(A1,2)>=6,
          COUNTIF(Holidays,INT(A1))>0),WORKDAY(A1,1),
     A1),
IF(OR(
          WEEKDAY(B1,2)>=6,
          COUNTIF(Holidays,INT(B1))>0),WORKDAY(B1,-1)+TIME(23,59,59),
     B1))-1-MOD(
IF(OR(
          WEEKDAY(A1,2)>=6,
          COUNTIF(Holidays,INT(A1))>0),WORKDAY(A1,1),
     A1),1)+MOD(
IF(OR(
          WEEKDAY(B1,2)>=6,
          COUNTIF(Holidays,INT(B1))>0),WORKDAY(B1,-1)+TIME(23,59,59),
     B1),1),"1:00"),0)
```

> **Example:**
>
> [image: Formula Example]
>
> 4) Format cell **D1** as **Time** with a Type of **37:30:55**
>
> [image: Format Cells]
>
> 5) Result example with start day/time on Saturday.
>
> [image: Result Example]
>
> Note: Above only shows one hour because the working day starts at midnight.

==============================================

### Expected Results

> 1) Return working hours between specified date/time.
>
> 2) Return 0 if there <=0 working hours between the specified date/time (i.e. start/end on same weekend).
>
> 3) Round to the nearest hour.
>
> 4) A workday is considered 24 hours.  *You could probably modify the formula for specific working hours, but that was not specified in the question.*

==============================================

### Sources Used

> [How to Calculate Hours in Excel Excluding Weekends](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/calculate-hours-excel-excluding-weekends-49927.html)
>
> [Extract a Date from a Date-Time Number in Excel](http://excelsemipro.com/2012/09/extract-a-date-from-a-date-time-number-in-excel/)
>
> [How can I test if a date is a workday?](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/352250-how-can-i-test-if-a-date-is-a-workday.html)
>
> [How to round time to nearest hour in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066173/how-to-round-time-to-nearest-hour-in-excel)